# finish() sometimes not working

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have different Level Classes which i call from one function.
The problem is that sometimes the Endscreen.Class doesn't get closed... But it happens only from Level5 and above.

My function in Endscreen.class:

```
public void NextLevel(View v){
    switch(currentLevel){
        case 1:
            Intent nLvl1 = new Intent (this, Level2.class);
            startActivity(nLvl1);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent nLvl2 = new Intent (this, Level3.class);
            startActivity(nLvl2);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent nLvl3 = new Intent (this, Level4.class);
            startActivity(nLvl3);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent nLvl4 = new Intent (this, Level5.class);
            startActivity(nLvl4);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent nLvl5 = new Intent (this, Level6.class);
            startActivity(nLvl5);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 6:
            Intent nLvl6 = new Intent (this, Level7.class);
            startActivity(nLvl6);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 7:
            Intent nLvl7 = new Intent (this, Level8.class);
            startActivity(nLvl7);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 8:
            Intent nLvl8 = new Intent (this, Level9.class);
            startActivity(nLvl8);
            finish ();
            break;
        case 9:
            Intent nLvl9 = new Intent (this, LevelSelect.class);
            startActivity(nLvl9);
            finish ();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix for this. For each intent, add this:

```
intentName.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

That'll get rid of the current activity the way you want it to `finish()`.

You can read the documentation on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Problem with:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```